# Google Assistant like UI

Tags: android, user-interface, bottom-sheet

So I've been working on an Android App and I want to design its interface to be almost exactly like the Google Assistant's UI.
The logical thing would be to use a BottomSheetDialogFragment, however, on expanding the bottom sheet, I have trouble keeping the chat interface (the edit text and the send button) anchored to the bottom of the BottomSheet. 

Is there any place where I can either get a tutorial on what I should do to fix this or where I can get a clone of the Google Assistant's UI?

With what I have now, the only problem is that the RecyclerView does not seem to be responding to scrolling.
Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_assistant_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_assistant_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_assistant_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ib_assistant_send"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="3dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_assistant_suggestions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/rl_assistant_chat"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_assistant_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/rv_assistant_suggestions"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Java file:

```
public void showAssistant() {
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_assistant, null);
    final BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
    final boolean[] flag = {true};
    dialog.setContentView(v);
    dialog.show();
    final RecyclerView rv_suggestions = dialog.findViewById(R.id.rv_assistant_suggestions),
            rv_chat = dialog.findViewById(R.id.rv_assistant_chat);
    final EditText et_message = dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_assistant_message);
    final ImageButton ib_send = dialog.findViewById(R.id.ib_assistant_send);
    final RelativeLayout rl_chat = dialog.findViewById(R.id.rl_assistant_chat);

    assert rv_chat != null && ib_send != null && rv_suggestions != null && et_message != null && rl_chat != null;

    final ArrayList<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    messages.add(new Message("Hey, what can I do for you?", true));

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rl_chat.getLayoutParams();

    suggestions.add("Schedule a meeting with the team");
    suggestions.add("Add a reminder");
    et_message.setEnabled(false);
    ib_send.setEnabled(false);
    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext),
            sManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    final MessageAdapter mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messages, mContext);


    final BottomSheetBehavior b = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) v.getParent());
    final SuggestionAdapter sAdapter = new SuggestionAdapter(suggestions, new SuggestionAdapter.SuggestionClicked() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String suggestion) {
            et_message.setText(suggestion);
            ib_send.callOnClick();
        }
    });
    ib_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String s = et_message.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!s.equals("")) {
                et_message.setText("");
                messages.add(new Message(s, false));
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messages.size() - 1);
                mManager.scrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
                handleResponse(s, messages, suggestions);
                sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messages.size()-1);

                if(flag[0]) {
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                    rl_chat.setLayoutParams(params);
                    b.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                    b.setSkipCollapsed(true);
                    flag[0] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    rv_chat.setLayoutManager(mManager);
    rv_suggestions.setLayoutManager(sManager);
    rv_chat.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rv_suggestions.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rv_chat.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    rv_suggestions.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    rv_chat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

}
public void handleResponse(String s, ArrayList<Message> messages, ArrayList<String> suggestions) {
    if(first) {
        messages.add(new Message("Wait till task data has been loaded please.", true));
    }
    else {
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        if (s.contains("meeting")) {
            //schedule meeting
            ArrayList<User> p = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String key : admins.keySet())
                p.add(new User(key, admins.get(key), true));
            for (String key : peopleMap.keySet())
                if(!admins.containsKey(key))
                    p.add(new User(key, peopleMap.get(key), true));
            messages.add(new Message(taskKey, p, Message.Companion.getTYPE_INVITEES()));
            suggestions.clear();
            suggestions.add("Select time");
            suggestions.add("Select time range");
            suggestions.add("Cancel");
        } else {
            //could not understand
            messages.add(new Message("I'm sorry, I didn't understand you, could you try again?", true));
        }
    }
}
```

Message is a custom class I defined that determines the type of message inflated in the RecyclerView.
Here is a link to a video of the output
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BymZtxAcj3obN3BoSGRPRS1faG9Za0YzbHdRNGdyTTlVdDE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post your layout files so that we have a look?